# How to mock ElasticSearch client specific method

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, testing, sinon

I have code in which I make a call to elasticsearch indices stats. Tried mocking it following way but did not work.

```
esIndicesStatsStub = sinon.stub(Client.indices.prototype, 'stats').returns({
        promise: () => new Error()
      })
```

The error I get is
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`
I've source code like this

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const esClient = new Client({
node:'some https url'
})
 esClient.indices.stats(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    if (data) {
    //do something 
                    } 
    //do some other thing
                }
    });
```

How do I mock elasticsearch properly with `sinon`? Because i'm not allowed to use `@elastic/elasticsearch-mock`

Comment: What's `Client`, please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ES SDK defines some APIs such as `indices` via the `getter` function:

```
Object.defineProperties(API.prototype, {
  //...
  indices: {
    get () { return this[kIndices] === null ? (this[kIndices] = new IndicesApi(this.transport)) : this[kIndices] }
  },
  //...
})
```

see [v8.5.0/src/api/index.ts#L372](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/v8.5.0/src/api/index.ts#L372)

We should use `stub.get(getterFn)` API to replace a new getter for this stub.

For these [APIs](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/v8.5.0/src/api/index.ts#L291) such as `.bulk`, `.clearScroll` which are assigned directly to `API.prototype`, you can call `sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'bulk')` to stub them.

At last, since your code is defined in the module scope, the code will be executed when you `import`/`require` it. We should arrange our stubs first, then `import`/`require` the module. As you can see, I use dynamic [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
const esClient = new Client({ node: 'http://localhost:9200' });
esClient.indices.stats({ index: 'a' }).then(console.log);
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
import { IndicesStatsResponse } from '@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/types';

describe('74949441', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const indicesStatsResponseStub: IndicesStatsResponse = {
      _shards: {
        failed: 0,
        successful: 1,
        total: 2,
      },
      _all: {
        uuid: '1',
      },
    };
    const indicesApiStub = {
      stats: sinon.stub().resolves(indicesStatsResponseStub),
    };
    sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'indices').get(() => indicesApiStub);
    await import('./');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(indicesApiStub.stats, { index: 'a' });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  74949441
{
  _shards: { failed: 0, successful: 1, total: 2 },
  _all: { uuid: '1' }
}
    ✓ should pass (609ms)


  1 passing (614ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

package versions:

```json
"@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.5.0",
"sinon": "^8.1.1",
"mocha": "^8.2.1",
```

Comment: Thanks for your response mate, once I try this, I'll mark it as an answer.